# Apache beam streaming pipeline deplyment doesn't exit

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a streaming apache beam pipeline that I want to deploy using DataflowRunner. My pipeline code looks something like this:

```
with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
    (p | "Read input from PubSub" >>
     beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=known_args.subscription)
     # ...
```

Then I deploy the pipeline like this `python3 main.py --runner=DataflowRunner --streaming ...` The pipeline is being deployed successfully but the problem is that the process does not end but continues to show logs coming from the workers.

Is there a way to start the pipeline, check that it's in a running state, and then exit the process?

Answer (score 2):

I believe when you are using `with beam.Pipeline() as p:' it will by default wait until the pipeline finishes or being terminated because it will invoke the '**enter**' and '**exit**' function on the pipeline, see https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/93c2bd8c8a7988f99a1299b9a1dd3a01122a35be/sdks/python/apache_beam/pipeline.py#L581.

Alternatively you can try

```
p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
p | ...
p.run()
```

Which should be non-blocking.

Comment: This is excellent and definitely the preferred way for any streaming jobs!!  I wish the documentation were more explicit on this point.  I will test this for myself now!  @Yichi , do you know if the third method, using `@` decorators, also is non-blocking?